# How to group MySQL query by multiple criterias?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have this table:

```
Table 'Receipts':

Fruit   |Receipt| Name
        |  No   |
--------|-------|-------
Apple   | 534   | Mike
Apple   | 422   | Mike
Apple   | 355   | Mike
Peach   | 646   | Robert
Banana  | 412   | Alex
Banana  | 124   | Alex
Banana  | 067   | Sam
Banana  | 975   | Sam
Banana  | 645   | Sam
```

And I want to display each unique combination, so each item every person has:

```
Apple   | Mike
Peach   | Robert
Banana  | Alex
Banana  | Sam
```

I can only manage to either group things by fruit or by name, no idea how I could get this done.
Can anybody help?

Comment: `GROUP BY Fruit, Name`

Comment: This doesnt work for me, it only outputs 3 results instead of 4

Comment: Both `SELECT Fruit, Name FROM tab GROUP BY Fruit, Name` or `SELECT DISTINCT Fruit, Name FROM tab` will return this result.

Comment: @robs This is not possible with the sample data you provide http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9441/1

Comment: ooops I have a question what server do you really use? MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: but anyway it works for both http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9441f/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Fruit, Name FROM tableName 
GROUP BY Fruit, Name
```

Or if you want to have a unique combination, you can even do it as

```
SELECT Fruit, Name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY concat(Fruit,'-', Name) //group the data based on unique word formed
```